# Angular ngx-datatable fixed column width is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I am using **swimlane's ngx-datatable**. I need to give specific widths to couple of columns in my table, but it is not working. This is how I create my table:

**page.component.html:**

```
<ngx-datatable [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns" rowHeight="auto" columnMode="force" [reorderable]="false" [swapColumns]="false"></ngx-datatable>
```

**page.component.ts:**

```
this.columns = [
   { prop: 'col1', resizeable: false, sortable: false, width: 30 }, 
   { prop: 'col2', resizeable: false }, 
   { prop: 'col3', resizeable: false, sortable: false }, 
   { prop: 'col4', resizeable: false, sortable: false },
   { prop: 'col5', resizeable: false, sortable: false, width: 30 }
];
```

Comment: Can you try to add these properties too? `minWidth: 30, maxWidth: 30`

Comment: @Akif it worked! Why it worked? :D

Comment: Divine providence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [the documentation](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/f870a877a88c3760e84748660933e92c98defe38/docs/api/column/inputs.md#minwidth-number), default value of the `minWidth` property is `100`. IMHO, if we try to define a `width` value smaller than `100`, then we need to define the `minWidth` property too.

> minWidth: number
>
> Minimum width of the column in pixels. Default value: 100